# Which files format should I favour for import into PostgreSQL+PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, file-formats

Although not a newbie, I am not a GIS expert, so I can use your help.

I have this GIS project, based on a PostgreSQL+PostGIS database. 
I import GIS data from many sources. Most of them offer several formats and ways to retrieve the data I will be needing, also because the data is often available from several servers (it's mostly governmental open data).

So far, we had been usually downloading manually shapefiles and importing them into the PSQL database using the shp2pgsql command line tool. We should also use some raster data in the future.

I intend to improve this by automating the whole procedure using Python scripts.
That led me to find out more about WFS servers. Most of the sources from which we need to retrieve data have WFS servers; it is often also possible to download files (.csv or zipped shapefiles) from the web sites. Retrieval from these sources can be automated either way (WFS or from the web sites).

I understood that when doing the http request to the WFS servers, there is the possibility to specify the wanted file format using the parameter `outputFormat`, although the queried server may only support certain formats.

**Question 1:** I have not found which file formats may be requested and how to interrogate the server about which file formats it supports.

**Question 2:** assuming that I have the choice, after stumbling onto the web site http://switchfromshapefile.org/, I know wonder which format I should favour for this use (import into my database). I understand that:

- Obviously a PSQL database dump is the best, but seldom available.
- Shapefiles not a great choice due to truncated names, absence of CRS definition, restricted number of supported datatypes, unspecified character set (we have a lot of é,è,ç,à here), etc...

But then, that still leaves me to choose between .gml, .gpkg, .kml, .geojson, ...

From what I read, .gpkg and .gml seems the best choice if I want to avoid losing information, albeit with the cost of increased file size.
What would you use?

Comment: One question per Question, please. *Opinion-based* questions are likely to be closed quickly. A question like this would be appropriate in [Chat], but Chat is *underutilized*, so you might not get many responses.

Comment: Did you try [GeoPackage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoPackage)? It's already flavored as a [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) DB and should meet part of your needs. I think it would be the closest to a PSQL DB. But the answer to your question highly depends on the target(s) you try to achieve obviously.

Comment: if most of the data is available as WFS why download the data ? (your download will get get out of date while the WFS should give you the latest updated data)

Comment: With ogr2ogr, you can simply retrieve data from WFS and load it directly into PostGIS using answer from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136995/wfs-to-vector-tiles Not need for intermediate data format between

Comment: Strictly speaking, the answer is rather simple: PostgreSQL/PostGIS does not favor any format, as it's purpose is not to provide an API other than `IMPORT` statements (except e.g. the `/COPY` interface, or data wrappers). You need an application as gateway, and it is completely up to you what formats it will (be able to) ingest. One of the most versatile tools for geodata available is *ogr2ogr* that covers most common formats, and which can e.g. be implemented dynamically as part of the Python GDAL/OGR bindings.

Comment: You can find formats that WFS service is supporting from GetCapabilities. But I recommend to use WFS with GML because it is the native format and it certainly does not alter or drop information.

Comment: ThomasG77's answer was what I needed : ogr2ogr seems to be right the tool I need. Trying me has led me to have questions about how to use it, though.

Comment: Also, refers to my other question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359630/missing-gml-id-when-using-ogr2ogr-from-wfs-to-postgis-gpkg-gml where I compare the various formats.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few different methods we use to ETL data into our system from external sources:

- Python is our main tool, with libraries for reading/writing to PostgreSQL (psycopg2) and MS SQL Server (pypyodbc)
- Using WGET, we can download shapefiles and CSVs to our servers
- For SHP and CSV, we create Foreign Data Wrappers to the files on disk, assuming they will remain in the same folder and with the same name
- We then use python to run a truncate (delete) and load (insert) from the FDW to the PGSQL tables
- Whenever we want to update one of the tables, we run a script that does the WGET and the truncate/load

  - We also pull a large chunk of addresses from the OpenAddresses.io project, which is set up using the .PBF format, which I believe is then pulled in via OGR2OGR with python.
- We're also doing a bit more with WFS, but nothing in our ETL is dependent on a WFS service at this point

Granted shapefiles are mainly used for polygon data from the City and County of Denver, and though the field name issue may be one thing, it can be overcome at the database level... I just care about the data, not the column names.