# Missing gml_id when using ogr2ogr from WFS to PostGIS / GPKG / GML

Tags: postgresql, wfs, ogr2ogr

I am trying to find the way to download on our PostgreSQL+PostGIS database the content of several WFS at regular intervals. It has to be done at regular intervals so we want to the whole thing to be completely automated, especially since there will be over a hundred layers coming from a dozen different WFS. Some WFS layers are quite huge.

After finding out the existence of ogr2ogr (thanks to ThomasG77), it seems the weapon of choice for downloading a WFS layer straight into the database.

So I have been running tests with one of the WFS layers (the smallest one) :
http://ws.carmencarto.fr/WFS/119/fxx_inpn?version=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=ms:Geoparcs

Here is the bash code used for my tests. Basically, it uses ogr2ogr to download the WFS layer in several formats : GeoJSON, shapefiles, GPKG, GML and into the Postgresql+PostGIS database.

```
destination_host='localhost'
destination_port='5432'
destination_user='my_user'
destination_password='my_pwd'
destination_dbname='Tests'
destination_schema='tests_ogr2ogr'
destination_table='Geoparcs'
destination_SRS='EPSG:2154'

source_url='http://ws.carmencarto.fr/WFS/119/fxx_inpn'
source_wfs_version='2.0.0'
source_layer_name='ms:Geoparcs'
source_SRS='EPSG:3857'

destination="host='${destination_host}' port='${destination_port}' dbname='${destination_dbname}' user='${destination_user}' password='${destination_password}'"
source="WFS:${source_url}?version=${source_wfs_version}&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=${source_layer_name}"

ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" -overwrite -progress "outputs/test_ogr2ogr-GPKG.gpkg" "${source}" 
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" -overwrite -progress "outputs/test_ogr2ogr-GeoJSON.geojson" "${source}" 
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -overwrite -progress  "outputs/test_ogr2ogr-SHP.shp" "${source}" 
ogr2ogr -f "GML" -overwrite -progress "outputs/test_ogr2ogr-GML.gml" "${source}" 
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" -overwrite -progress -s_srs "${source_SRS}" -t_srs "${destination_SRS}" PG:"${destination}" "${source}" -nln "${destination_schema}.${destination_table}"
```

**Results** : it works fine for shapefiles and GeoJSON but fails for GML, Postgresql and GPKG with basically the same error :

- GPKG : "*failed to execute insert : NOT NULL constraint failed: ms:Geoparcs.gml_id*"
- GML : "*Field gml_id has a NULL content which is not allowed*"
- PostgreSQL : "*null value in column "gml_id" violates not-null constraint*"

From [what I can read](https://www.wetransform.to/news/2018/02/12/best-practices-for-inspire-ids/), in GML, there is a mandatory unique identifier field named *gmal:id*.
I am not sure why GPKG and Postgresql also stumble on an error that should be a peculiarity of GML ... Would ogr2ogr when asked to ETL from WFS to GPKG/Postgresql use GML as an intermediate format ?

Now, when I have a look at http://ws.carmencarto.fr/WFS/119/fxx_inpn?version=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=ms:Geoparcs using a browser, I see no attribute "gml:id=" in any tag that would be empty.
Visualizing this WFS layer straight into QGIS does not show any *gml_id* attribute. I suppose because it is a system attribute of no interest in the GUI.

Also, using ogrinfo :

```
$ ogrinfo "WFS:http://ws.carmencarto.fr/WFS/119/fxx_inpn?version=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=ms:Geoparcs" ms:Geoparcs -so
ERROR 1: Server is read-only WFS; no WFS-T feature advertized
Had to open data source read-only.
INFO: Open of `WFS:http://ws.carmencarto.fr/WFS/119/fxx_inpn?version=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=ms:Geoparcs'
      using driver `WFS' successful.
Metadata:
  PROVIDER_NAME=Muséum national d Histoire naturelle
  TITLE=MNHN - INPN - Metropole

Layer name: ms:Geoparcs
Metadata:
  TITLE=Géoparcs
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 7
Extent: (577022.800000, 6287714.438800) - (997466.471300, 6596522.856900)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["RGF93 / Lambert-93",
    GEOGCS["RGF93",
        DATUM["Reseau_Geodesique_Francais_1993",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6171"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],
        AXIS["Longitude",EAST],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4171"]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",49],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",44],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",46.5],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",3],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",700000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",6600000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","2154"]]
Geometry Column = msGeometry
gml_id: String (0.0) NOT NULL
ID_LOCAL: String (0.0)
ID_MNHN: String (0.0)
P1_NATURE: String (0.0)
P2_CULTURE: String (0.0)
P3_PAYSAGE: String (0.0)
P4_GEOLOGI: String (0.0)
P5_SPELEO: String (0.0)
P6_ARCHEO: String (0.0)
P7_PALEOB: String (0.0)
P8_ANTHROP: String (0.0)
P9_SCIENCE: String (0.0)
P10_PUBLIC: String (0.0)
P11_DD: String (0.0)
P12_AUTRE: String (0.0)
NOM_SITE: String (0.0)
URL_FICHE: String (0.0)
SURF_OFF: String (0.0)
ACTE_FIN: String (0.0)
GEST_SITE: String (0.0)
OPERATEUR: String (0.0)
PRECISION: String (0.0)
SRC_GEOM: String (0.0)
SRC_ANNEE: String (0.0)
MARIN: String (0.0)
DATE_CREA: String (0.0)
MODIF_ADM: String (0.0)
MODIF_GEO: String (0.0)
ACTE_DEB: String (0.0)
NOM: String (0.0)
URL: String (0.0)
```

So, **how do I get rid of this error and download this layer into my postgresql ?**

Comment: Also, to see the capabilities of the server :
http://ws.carmencarto.fr/WFS/119/fxx_inpn?version=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Comment: I just tried importing the generated GeoJSON into Postgresql using ogr2ogr and it seems to work. The layers then include as attributes (columns in Postresql), gml_id and ogc_fid .

Comment: And from what I can see in the WFS specifications, the WFS server may allow as output formats : GML, GeoJSON, shapefile and csv.
So I suppose, that since GML being considered the default format, when the destination is any other format, ogr2ogr will query the server for GML and then transform it into the requested format, hence the error.

Comment: GML is the default output of a WFS which is why ogr2ogr is using it, the other errors come from constructing the tables to match the expected GML schema (that the WFS server told them) which says there is an unique id while you are trying to load NULL for all of them

Comment: Looks like the MapServer that is providing the WFS is misconfigured - it should specify one of gml_identifier, wfs_featureid or ows_featureid for each layer. See https://mapserver.org/id/ogc/wfs_server.html

Comment: The GML  output shows even a very clear hint for the admins: `<!-- WARNING: No featureid defined for typename 'Geoparcs'. Output will not validate. -->`

Comment: If you want to use this misconfigured server and find a workaround for saving the data directly into PostGIS without going through some other format that does not support NOT NULL constraint please edit the title and question for making it clear.

Comment: It looks like the best I can do is the workaround of using GoeJSON as an intermediate format.

Comment: whilst the WFS specification allows for the provider to have multiple outputs, in this service GeoJSON is not supported only ~ `application/gml+xml; version=3.2, text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1, text/xml; subtype=gml/2.1.2, SHAPE, MIDMIF, KML`

Comment: on syntax, note for GetFeature in a version 2.0.0 request, you should use typenameS, not typename

Answer (score 5):

Try to use `ogr2ogr` with `-forceNullable` option.

Comment: Had a similar problem trying to convert a GML document where features did not have GML IDs (which is perfectly valid). Adding the option as described here lead to the conversion (to Geopackage) succeeding